# Toolbar actionButton disappeared and not showing again

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm working with a toolbar that has a search action button, it was used to work and suddenly it stopped showing it to me. This is my code:

In my menu folder

**menu_feed.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

</menu>
```

This is the class where i call that item and inflates it into the toolbar

**FeedFragment.class**

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
        setupToolbar(v);
        return v;
    }

    private void setupToolbar(View v) {
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setupRV();

        mFeedPostsPresenter = new FeedPostsPresenterImpl(this);
    }

    private void setupRV() {

        mFeedPostsRV = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.feed_posts_list);

        mFeedPostsRV.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        mFeedPostsRV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator itemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
        itemAnimator.setAddDuration(1000);
        itemAnimator.setRemoveDuration(1000);
        mFeedPostsRV.setItemAnimator(itemAnimator);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_feed, menu);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search){
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchUsersActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

For some reason I don't know why this search button disappeared from my toolbar and I can't see it again, this is my output from menu_feed.xml:

[image]

And in runtime inside my app there is no action_search:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "collapseActionView" allows the button to be shown but as a widget. This button can be dynamic, like a search button that expands. Check this: [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/). Try deleting this in your **menu_feel.xml**

Comment: yes, i have tried it before and its the same, if i just let app:showAsAction="always" its the same

Comment: Try adding this: `android:orderInCategory="100"`